# Solve Incorrect encoding to upload CSV to Google Cloud Platform AI Dataset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataset, automl

I just started with GCP IA and tried to import a dataset.

Following the official documentation [Preparing your training data](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/prepare)

> The CSV file can have any filename, must be UTF-8 encoded, and must end with a .csv extension.

Following these instructions above and be certified that the file is correct

[image]

However, after importing dataset to GCP the document lost their encoding.

[image]

What should i do to upload with correct text encoding.

I Already tried to upload iso-8859-1 encoded file but i got following error:

```
Due to an error, AI Platform was unable to import data into dataset "...".
Additional Details:
Operation State: Failed with errors
Resource Name: 
projects/ ...
Error Messages: INTERNAL
```

Comment: Which product are you using exactly? Are you using AI on text files?